# uitextfield hide keyboard?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

On the iphone.  When I press on the `uitextfield` I don't want a keyboard to popup.

I want the same behavior, just no keyboard at all.  How can I hide/close the keyboard when the user presses the `uitextfield`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want the exact same behavior, without the keyboard, try

```
textfield.inputView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 6):

Returning NO to `UITextFieldDelegate`'s `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` should do it.

Comment: This is stupid but how do i do this? I tried returning NO in my viewcontroller but nothing happens ..

Comment: It's easy, your viewController should be the delegate of the textfield (you can do this in interface Builder), then you just implement the function in your viewController and return NO. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

`textfield resignFirstResponder`

in delegate method -

`(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)`

textField like this:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == yourTextField){
      [yourTextfield resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this method to dismiss a keyboard touch anywhere in the view

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

or
by clicking on keyboard done button

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```