# How to make a UITextField selectable but not editable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I hope that user can copy and paste the text but not edit them. I use a delegate `UITextField`  method to implement this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range       replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    return NO;
}
```

In this way although the text is selectable and not editable, but when you select the text, the keyboard always shows up, which is a little bit annoying cause you can not edit the text. So is there anyway to make text selectable and not editable, without showing the keyboard?

Comment: have you tried calling `[textField resignFirsResponder]` at first in your `delegate` method. Frankly, I dont have any idea how it would behave. just asking.

Comment: You can also try to subclass UITextField - override `becomeFirstResponder1 method and return `NO but I think that will prevent user from pasting text.

Answer (score 14):

What you need is to allow the control to receive all user interaction events. So, do not `return NO` from `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`. Instead, do the following:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    return textField != _yourReadOnlyTextField;
}
```

This will allow the user to select the text and also to select options like `Cut`, `Copy` and `Define` from the popup menu.

**UPDATE:**

Also, for completeness, you may want to prevent the keyboard from showing up at all on readyonly textfields. So based on the accepted answer to this question: [uitextfield hide keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478719/uitextfield-hide-keyboard), you may want to add:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // Prevent keyboard from showing up when editing read-only text field
    _yourReadOnlyTextField.inputView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}
```

Comment: Very nice.  Exactly what is needed to be able to select and copy text without changing the text.

Comment: Good solution, but the text cursor is still there.

Comment: My textfield was in a UITableViewCell so I checked 

return textfield.tag != 200

Answer (score 5):

Update for Swift users:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    return textField != self.yourReadOnlyTextField;
}
```

and when the view loads

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.selfCodeEdit.inputView = UIView.init();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you have more then one textFields you can do in this way

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField == firstTextField || textField == secondTextField {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should implement another `UITextField`'s delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    return NO;
}
```

//UPDATE Also, there is a questions like this here [How to disable UITextField's edit property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355720/how-to-disable-uitextfields-edit-property).

Comment: This won't allow the user to paste text. Have a look at the accepted answer here for a solution that should work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478719/uitextfield-hide-keyboard

Comment: I tried this. But the text is neither selectable nor editable with this delegate method, just like a UIlabel.

Comment: i want to copy the text from textfield by long pressing the textfield; But also want not make it editable. What should i do?

Answer (score -3):

You can do that directly through the storyboard.
Select your `UITextView` then in your **Attributes** inspector.
You have some behavior params :

[image]

Comment: Question is about `UITextField` not `UITextView`