# Remove keyboard before pushing new viewcontroller

Tags: ios, keyboard

When I select some textfields I push a new viewcontroller. So I have to hide keyboard before loading the new view controller. But when the new view appears the keyboard is still there. resignkeyboard and [self.view endEditing:YES]; doesn't work. How can I remove keyboard for the new view controller. Thank you.

Comment: can you show the code ? 
or should try 
[yourTExtField resignFirstResponder];

Comment: Do you allow user to type anything in the text field? If No means call resign firstResponse in the delegate method didBeginEditing..

Comment: I can't show you any code. Because there is nothing to show. It's just a normal UITextField.:/ I allow user interactions. So didbeginediting delegate fired everytime that I touch textfield. I put resignfirstrepsponder and endediting functions into viewWillLayoutSubviews. viewwilldisappear or viewdiddisappear can't be used for this situation. Because I use addSubview method to call new viewcontroller with animation. But none of them works.

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478719/uitextfield-hide-keyboard/23220446#23220446

Comment: It didn't work. It just not disappear. :/ When I tap the textfield which has to show no keyboard it just not disappears.The keyboard of the previous textfield just show up. Maybe I have to not use textfield.

Answer (score 3):

before going to new viewController do

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

or

call resignFirstResponder method to all yourTextFields.

Answer (score 0):

As Madhur said its right, if you have [yourTExtField resignFirstResponder]; code before going to new view Controller its should work. If you put your code snippet then i can try to provide you the exact solution.